# ElasticsearchにImage Pluginを追加したい

Tags: java, centos, elasticsearch

次のHPを参考に、ElasticsearchにImage Pluginを追加したいと考えております。

https://medium.com/@kwendomi/elasticsearch-4812fc11c5ca

導入先の環境がネットワークに接続できないため、プラグインを別環境からダウンロードして追加しようと試みているのですが、インストールエラーが発生してしまいます。

導入先環境

```
centOS
install file:elasticsearch-image-master.zip
java : 1.8.0_60
ElasticSearch : 1.1.0
lucene version : 4.7
```

インストールコマンド

```
elasticsearch/bin/plugin -u file///bin/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-image-master.zip -i com.github.kzwang/elasticsearch-image/1.3.0
```

エラーメッセージ

```
Message:
Error while installing plugin, reason: IllegalArgumentException:
Plugin installation assumed to be site plugin, but contains source
code, aborting installation.
```

どうか、ご教示のほどお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

GitHubからソースコードをZipでダウンロードしてないでしょうか。
ソースはMavanでビルドしないといけません。
ちょうど類似の質問があったのでこちらを参考にして下さい。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283057/elasticsearch-building-and-installing-plugins

Comment: 回答、また参考のURLありがとうございます。

仰るとおり、ソースコードをzipでダウンロードしておりました。
Mavenでビルドした上で、再配置してみます。

ありがとうございます。